# PHP pdo trying to insert to mysql without success

Tags: php, pdo, insert, sql-insert

I am working on my script 1 month now I tried to insert data to mysql but i got an error

Error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on string

```
$post_id = $_GET['post_id']; // VALUE : "23"
$season = $_GET['season']; // Value : "2"

$statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO seasons (post_id, season) VALUES(?, ?)");
$statement->execute(array($post_id, $season));
```

I am using this way to insert all the time but now its  not working well..

```html
    class db {
        private $link;

        public function __construct () {
            $this->link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        }

        public function getLink () {
            return $this->link;
        }
    }

    $db = new db;

    try {
        $link = $db->getLink();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die('Database Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Where are you defining `$link`?

Comment: @aynber updated

Comment: Try `var_dump($link);` to see what it really contains. The error says it's a string instead of the PDO connection, so something else is going on there.